# Where is my compiled coffee script js file?

Tags: scala, playframework, coffeescript

I have a play 2.5.x app and I created the file in the following folder:

```
/app/assets/javascript/test.coffee
```

In my master.scala.html I have:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/test.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My plugins.sbt has:

```
// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.2")
```

When I run the app it doesn't create the file in my `/public/javascript/test.js` folder.

Trying to navigate to the file is a file not found error:

```
http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/test.js
```

My routes has:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

**How should this be working as I have never used this before?**

Reference:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsCoffeeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake:
You have to put the `test.coffee` file in the folder `/app/assets/javascripts/` - there is a **`s`** at the end of javascript**s**.
Then it should work.

Also you should know that the compiled `test.js` file will **not** be put in the `/public/javascript/` folder. Instead play uses the `target` folder for all compiled code (`*.class` files, compiled assets like your `*.coffee` file, etc.). In your particular case the compiled JavaScript file will be put in `target/web/public/main/javascripts/` where play will pick it up when serving the file to a client. Just have a look through the `target` folder to get an idea of how Play organizes compiled resources. Tip: In case something doesn't work, doesn't compile etc. where you think it should it may sometimes is a got idea to just delete the `target` folder to start "fresh". (Or just use `sbt clean` or `activator clean`).

Comment: it worked but the generated file is in ```/assets/javascripts/test.js``` the documentation also says it will be in the public folder.

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. Yes the file can be accessed **from the browser** via `/assets/javascripts/test.js` - but **on the filesystem** it is **not** put in the `public` folder of your project but in the `target` folder.